# How should I use lists of instances in django

Tags: django

I'm trying to use some kind of list of objects in django.

So I have different database entries:

```
class A(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

I would like to link these database entries with other database entries

```
class B(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   list<A> = ???
```

I would normally store a list of class A instances in class B, but in django?
Each instance of class A has an ID in the database.
So you would have to create a table for each instance of class B, in whose rows these IDs of class A are stored. But how do I do it?

can someone please show and explain me a simple example?

thx

EDIT ADD:
ok sorry the question was asked wrong.
I mean the following:
I have a manytomany field `bla = models.ManyToManyField ('A')` in B. How can I now add the data in the view:

```
 a = get_object_or_404 (A, id = request.POST.get ('a_id'))
 b = get_object_or_404 (B, id = request.POST.get ('b_id'))
 b.bla.add (a)
 b.save ()
```

does not work (print (a) and print (b) are corrected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on whats your planned relations will be. Can `B` be related to multiple `A` records? If yes, then you may want to use [many to many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) field:

```
class B(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   publications = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

If each `B` can be related only with single `A` then probably your choise is [foreign key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships):

```
class B(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   publications = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In both cases you can then fetch the list of related objects using query.

But what you can't actually do in this way is to simply define an array field an put `B` instances in there (ask this question - how they will be stored in DB?).
If you are using PostgreSQL you may actually use an [array field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField) and store `A` id's there.

Answer (score 0):

Having a list of `A` instances for each `B` instance, requires a `ForeignKey` field in `A`, not a field in `B`. This is because a list of `A`s in a `B` means that multiple instances of `A` belong to a single instance of `B`.

Consider the following code:

```py
class B(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)


class A(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name='As')
```

Then to access the list of `A`s for an instance of `B`, use:

```py
b = B.objects.first() # or any instance of b, this is just an example
list_of_As_in_b = b.As.all()
```

Read about [Many-to-one relationships](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fi/SSWU4L/Data/imc_Data/Data_q_a_watson_assistant/What_is_a_many-to-one_relationship.html) in general and [ForeignKeys in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/#many-to-one-relationships) for complete understanding of how this works on the database level and in Django.

Comment: ok thx, in the database it is now correct. How can I now represent this in a form, so that you can now select an instance and this is then saved?

Comment: @Metatron Can you elaborate? Maybe give an example? Are you choosing an instance of A or B?

Comment: for example, i created various objects from A. now i need an interactive page where i can create an object B and add it from a list of objects A.

Comment: @Metatron You want to create a `forms.Select` and add it as `widget` to your form. Checkout this example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#iterating-relationship-choices